# How to redirect 404 page to other domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I changed my my website from a cms to WordPress. So the URL links were changed. 
Now google redirects users to old URL links. Which is dead now. So the website returns 404 page.

Visitors complaining me about the error. 
So i want to redirect the users with 404 error URL to another subdomain.

Error URL : website.com/ABC/123

To URL : old.website.com/ABC/123

How can i do it with editing .htaccess file. 
Already there's some data on htaccess file.

My Htaccess file screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFYN2.jpg

What changes are needed on htaccess file to redirect only 404 URLs to my subdomain.

I've hundreds of links so i can't add it manually via redirect plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if that page is a 404 error page and redirect to your subdomain if that is an error page. Wordpress has a function called `is_404()` which checks for 404 error page. For redirection, it has a function called `wp_redirect('redirect url')`. For redirection to the same URL with other domain name, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` function of PHP for getting the URL (in your case this will return `/ABC/123`)

So your code should be:

```
if (is_404()) { 
    wp_redirect('http://old.website.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

Add this code in `header.php` or your `index.php` file of your theme or else you can also hook this into your header in your custom plugin.

---

Java Script Approach

Add this code in the same place instead of previous code (before end of head tag in header.php)

```
<?php
if (is_404()) {
    ?>
        <script>
           window.location = "http://old.website.com"+window.location.pathname;
        </script>
    <?php
   exit;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I added it on header.php file under body tag. Its not working. Still showing the same 404 error. 

I tried it under head tag even that it's not working.

Comment: try to add these lines before the end of head tag. Did you include **php** tags this way **<?php** if (is_404()) { 
    wp_redirect('http://old.website.com'+$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
} **?>**

Comment: sorry forgot to add exit after wp_redirect. Try adding that once and check .

Comment: Can you type it what exactly I've to type and where to type.

Comment: Thanks. But still it's not working. 
Now the difference was the page was not loading now. 
Simply blank page was displayed. It's not redirecting the page to subdomain URL.

Comment: Try the Java Script Approach that i added now

Comment: + sign to concatenate php? isn't it supposed to be a dot?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");

header("Location: http://old.website.com{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"); 

exit();

?>
```

Simply add this to your 404.php

Comment: its redirect the permalink that have the same structure to http://old.website.com

which was suppose to bring error on website.com